# Azure Function store requests and trigger the funtion again later

Tags: azure, queue, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Function that will take a POST request , do some processing and then sends a POST to another Endpoint with the content of the input request.

I have the requirement, that I somehow have to store all the incoming requests and after a fixed time period the Azure Function needs to send the same POST request again.

What I could do is, set up a cloud storage where I store all the incoming requests and have a second Azure Function with a timer trigger that reads from the storage and sends the request again. My problem with this is, that I have to set up an additional storage and I am looking for a more cost efficient method.

Does anyone know an alternative way to "store" incoming requests and have the same Azure Funtion pick them up again later?

Comment: Storage is cheap on azure. not sure to understand what you're trying to do. So people send data and you kind of batch these requests and send them to another endpoint ? what is the reason behind that ? could you please elaborate on your usecase ?

Comment: Can your 2nd request be processed by a different Function?

Comment: The use case is a alerting system. Essentially the functions takes a request, brings it to a new payload format and then forwards it. I have to batch the requests, because i have to send the same request again with a "delete flag" to delete the alert. this is a failsave, because I don't want to fill up the alert backlog too much

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is durable functions which can handle exactly this kind of scenario and it'll do all the complicated parts of storing state/context during delays. They are backed by Azure storage but as has been said this is one of the cheapest services available on Azure.

For what you've described you might want to do a combination of [function chaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#chaining):

[image]

Combined with a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp) in between the processing you do in chained functions:

```
//do some initial processing (possibly in an Activity function)
//...

DateTime waitTime = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
await context.CreateTimer(waitTime, CancellationToken.None);

//call the next activity function (parameters can also be passed in)
await context.CallActivityAsync("DoNextSetOfThings");
```

High level what you'd have is something along the lines of:

1. An HTTP endpoint which you POST to initially
2. An Orchestrator function which handles the chaining and delays
3. One or more Activity functions that do the work and can accept parameters and return results to the Orchestrator

Comment: Thank you! I going to look into it. Seems like a good solution to what I want